# Choose 9 sets of 5 random items from Array without repeating them with Javascript

Tags: javascript

So I have an array with 45 items, each item has 2 items, local and visitor team.

I need to create a function that creates 9 matchdays with 5 games in each matchday, but the games can't repeat.

I tried doing this:

```
const getRandomGame = (items, idsToAvoid) => {
  const game = getRandomFromArray(items);

  if (idsToAvoid.includes(game[0].id, game[1].id))
    return getRandomGame(items, idsToAvoid);

  return game;
};

const getRandomFromArray = (items) => {
  return items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];
};


// this is inside another function that tries to generate the matchdays
for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    counter++;
    let games = [];
    let avoidIds = [];

    for (let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
      const game = getRandomGame(copyFinalGames, avoidIds);

      const localRng = Math.random() < 0.5;
      const local = localRng ? game[0] : game[1];
      const visitor = localRng ? game[1] : game[0];

      avoidIds.push(local.id, visitor.id);

      games.push({
        id: counter,
        local,
        visitor,
      });

      copyFinalGames = copyFinalGames.filter(
        (item) => !(item[0].id === game[0].id && item[1].id === game[1].id)
      );
    }

    gamedays.push({
      id: i + 1,
      games,
    });
  }
```

Which doesn't quite work (games are being repeated) + it's not efficient cause it tries to brute force the rule out repeated games. Any ideas?

The original array looks like this:

```
[{ id: 1 }, { id: 2}],
[{ id: 3 }, { id: 4}],
[{ id: 5 }, { id: 6}] // here only showing three rows, but it has the 45 possible games
```

Comment: Can the games not repeat on a given matchday or throughout the whole series? Is it a two-team combination you don't want repeated or an individual team?

Comment: How can you make 45 games out of 6 teams? If each team plays every other team, once local and once as visitor. You have at most 30 unique matches (6 * 5). Where `{ local: "a", visitor: "b" }` and `{ local: "b", visitor: "a" }` does not count as duplicate. If you want 45 games, there is bound to be at least 15 duplicate match-ups.

Comment: There are 10 teams, I only put 6 to show the structure of the original array @3limin4t0r

Comment: @BenjaminPenney the same team cannot play twice in a matchday

Comment: Assuming the array snippet was meant to have containing array brackets (as shown, it is a list of arrays), you have an array of 45 elements, each of which contains an array of two elements, each of which contains an object. If each pair of objects is to be used once and once only, simply remove the array containing the objects from the outer array using `array.slice()` when it is chosen.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's an attempt:

```js
const matchupList =
[
    [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2}],
    [{ id: 3 }, { id: 4}],
    [{ id: 5 }, { id: 6}],
    [{ id: 6 }, { id: 5}],
    [{ id: 3 }, { id: 9}],
    [{ id: 8 }, { id: 2}],
    [{ id: 4 }, { id: 1}],
    [{ id: 2 }, { id: 6}],
    [{ id: 7 }, { id: 8}],
    [{ id: 5 }, { id: 3}],
    [{ id: 3 }, { id: 1}],
    [{ id: 2 }, { id: 7}],
    [{ id: 7 }, { id: 1}],
    [{ id: 4 }, { id: 6}],
    [{ id: 7 }, { id: 2}],
    [{ id: 8 }, { id: 1}],
    [{ id: 9 }, { id: 3}],
    [{ id: 5 }, { id: 4}],
    [{ id: 5 }, { id: 0}],
    [{ id: 0 }, { id: 3}],
    [{ id: 1 }, { id: 0}],
    [{ id: 0 }, { id: 8}],
    [{ id: 9 }, { id: 8}]
];

const pickMatch = (list) => list[Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length)];

const pickMatchDay = (matchupList, matchDaySize) =>
{
    let matchChosen;
    let teamSeen;
    let workingList;

    do
    {
        matchChosen = [];
        teamSeen = [];
        // Create a copy of the original matchup list so we can remove matches we've already tried
        workingList = matchupList.concat();
        while(matchChosen.length < matchDaySize && workingList.length)
        {
            let local, visitor;

            let teamPairing = pickMatch(workingList);
            let fromId = matchupList.indexOf(teamPairing);
            teamPairing = teamPairing.map(i => i.id);
            // If this pairing has NO teams we've already seen...
            if(teamPairing.findIndex(i => teamSeen.includes(i)) === -1)
            {
                // Randomly decide who is local/visitor
                if(Math.random() < 0.5)
                    [local, visitor] = teamPairing;
                else
                    [visitor, local] = teamPairing;
                matchChosen.push(
                {
                    id: matchChosen.length + 1,
                    local,
                    visitor,
                    fromId
                });
                // Push this pairing's teams to the list of teams we've seen
                teamSeen.push(...teamPairing);
            }
            // Remove this matchup from the possible matchups we can choose
            workingList.splice(workingList.indexOf(teamPairing), 1);
        }
        // Due to the limited number of pairings available (and that pairings are variable),
        // it's quite possible we'll reach this point with only 3 or 4 matches chosen,
        // but having exhausted all available matchups.
        // If this happens, we start over.
        // Not really necessary if you can guarantee 45 matchups and 5 matches per day
    } while(matchChosen.length < matchDaySize);

    return(matchChosen);
};

const gamedays = [];

for(let index = 0; index < 5; index++)
    gamedays.push({id: index + 1, games: pickMatchDay(matchupList, 5)});

console.log(gamedays);
```

Some notes:

Pairings can still be repeated across different days. You might find that team 1 plays team 2 on both day 1 and day 3, for instance.

pickMatchDay has a real possibility of infinitely looping, e.g. you can ask for 6 games, which is just impossible with only 10 teams.